# python manage.py runserver works fine, but cannot run urls.py without getting import error

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am following the djangobook website.  I am just starting out, and my project structure looks like this:

```
mysite
    mysite
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
```

The outer mysite lives in a directory that is on the pythonpath.  Therefore, if I want to import something from views.py in a python console, I have to construct an import:

```
from mysite.mysite.views import hello
```

However, the actual implementation in urls.py that currently works when running the server is:

```
from mysite.views import hello
```

If I try to import hello by using this single mysite relative import in a console, it will fail.  How come it does not fail when I execute:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

?

Here is the traceback of the failed import, and then a successful import:

```
(django_env) C:\>python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC                                     
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mysite.views import hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mysite.views'
>>> from mysite.mysite.views import hello
>>>
```

Comment: how do you import in the shell? show the import code with full error traceback

Comment: added failed import and successful import

Comment: why do you run `python` and not python manage.py shell. Also your path to module is incorrect. There is no module in mysite.views although there is mysite.mysite.views.

Comment: I suppose I am asking how django framework effectively brings the inner mysite directory onto the pythonpath. If it does it by running django.setup(), then what does it do specifically to make the magic happen?

Comment: it does not have much to do with pythonpath. It works based on modules not python paths. Your every folder has a init file which does the magic

Comment: The outer mysite is not a package but the inner one is.  I do not understand what you are trying to tell me with that comment.

Comment: Why did you put the directory containing the outer `mysite` on your python path? You want the outer `mysite/` directory on your path, not the directory containing it, so `manage.py` is at the root of your path.

Comment: The directory outside mysite is just where I have my workspace.  I just created the mysite project in my workspace.  Again, I can run the website without changing anything, I am just wondering what happens in django.setup() that allows for the code that follows to act as though the inner mysite is on the pythonpath.